# WiX remove LocalAppData (AppData\Local\my_app_folder) on uninstall

Tags: wix, local, uninstallation, appdata

I have a wix setup project which creates a ProgramMenu shortcut and a Desktop shortcut. I am able to remove these shortcuts by using **RemoveFolder**.

```
<!-- To remove Desktop shortcut -->
<RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>

<!-- To remove ProgramMenu shortcut-->
<RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpShortCut" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
```

However, on uninstall, I also want to be able to clear the current user's [LocalAppData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369768(v=vs.85).aspx). More specifially, Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Local\my_application

So far, I have figured out that the **RemoveFolder** does not remove files recursively and that I would have to use 
[util:RemoveFolderEx](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html). This is how I have done it:

```
  <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder" Name="Local">
    <Directory Id="RemoveLocalData" Name="my_application">
      <Component Id="RemoveLocalAppData" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="RemoveLocalData"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveLocalData" On="uninstall"/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

> And I get this error: 
>  
>   ICE38:
>   Component RemoveLocalAppData installs to user profile. It must use a
>   registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.

I figure I am not using **RemoveFolderEx** properly, but I do not know the right way in this case to clear my LocalAppData.

Note, I do not create the folder during installation. Instead, this [LocalAppData]\my_application is created post-installation at run-time by the application.

Comment: I have found a link that may be useful for this issue. Will update post if it solves my issue.
https://pkisensee.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/windows-installer-removing-folders/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to delete current user's LocalAppData(cache) with help from the following the link: https://pkisensee.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/windows-installer-removing-folders/

In order to successfully delete the application's LocalAppData folder, I would have to search the registry (using **RegistrySearch**) for the location of the application cache folder and store it in a **Property**.

```
<Property Id="CACHEFOLDER">
     <RegistrySearch Key="Software\CompanyName\AppName" Root="HKCU" Type="raw"
                     Id="CacheFolderRegSearch" Name="CachePath" />
</Property>
```

However, at the moment this registry entry does not exist, and the path would not be resolved. Hence during installation, I have to save the location of the LocalAppData cache folder in the registry, so that on uninstall, I can do a **RegistrySearch** and remove the cache folder recursively by **util:RemoveFolderEx**.

To do that, I set the **RegistryValue** in a component as such:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- This is the name of the cache folder in LocalAppData -->
    <!-- In this case the cache folder is in \Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Local\MyAppCache -->
    <?define AppCacheFolder = "MyAppCache" ?>
    <Component Id="CacheCleanup" Guid="*">
         <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\CompanyName\AppName" Name="CachePath" 
                        Type="string" Value="[LocalAppData]$(var.AppCacheFolder)"                   
                        KeyPath="yes" />
         <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="CACHEFOLDER"/>
    </Component>

    <!-- ... -->

</Directory>
```

> Note that this is done within the **TARGETDIR** directory

And finally, need to register that component into a **Feature**

```
<Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="App Name" Level="1">
    <!-- Other Components -->
    <ComponentRef Id="CacheCleanup" />
</Feature>
```

Comment: Note that in WiX 3.11.1 I had to use [LocalAppDataFolder] instead of [LocalAppData]

Comment: What if someone externally sets the "CachePath" registry value to "C:/" before the uninstaller is run? Will the uninstaller then go on to delete all files on the partition without warning?

Comment: That's a brilliant question! It's been years since I've last worked on this, so I'm not entirely sure myself. Might need someone with better understanding/experience to answer that. All I can say is to make sure that the applicaiton's `CachePath` registry value is protected from modications?

Comment: It's late but it may help others, you can use [AppDataFolder] instead of LocalAppData to reach \Users\CurrentUser\AppData\\Roaming\